# How can I create an array that is dependent upon the size of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```java
public void methodName(ArrayList<Object> list, double[] priceList){...}
```

This method is supposed to take an `ArrayList` of objects paired with their price as an array of double values. I need the array to be the same size as the `ArrayList`.

Is it possible to call a method within the declaration? `(double[list.size()])` What are other solutions to this problem?

Comment: You cannot fix that inside the method. Both the list and the array get passed to the method, so the caller is in control over the lengths of these parameters. Call you can do inside the method is check if the lengths match.

Comment: Did you write this code? Don't pass separate lists or arrays of primitive data like `double`s and try to synchronize them; create a class that encapsulates the object data including price, and put the logic in the class. And prices should be fixed-point, not `double`.

Comment: The only solution is to check and throw and IllegalArgumentException if the two don't match.

Comment: as they said, it's not possible.  you should try inside curly brackets {} what you are trying to do and not in the parameter of the method.

Comment: This is called an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/135230); you want X but you don't know how to get it. You thought that “create an Array that is dependent upon the size of an ArrayList” would X, but now you find that won't X. You need to explain what X is. Why are you doing that? What is your goal?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that. Since the method receives the array as a parameter you can not change its size. You can however check inside the method if both lengths match depending on what you wish to accomplish. I am not sure what your constraints are, but it seems like this can be easily done where the method is called before the call.